# Calling Javascript function on multiple occasions

Tags: jquery

So, I have three scenarios which requires js.

One is "before rendered" and other is "after rendered" and last one is when none of above is required.

Here is an example (current setup):

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {

 //Before rendered
 jQuery('#button_A').click(function(){
      jQuery('#button_B').click();
    });

 //After Rendered
 jQuery.example().on('rendered', function(items) {
    jQuery('#button_A').click(function(){
      jQuery('#button_B').click();
    });
 });

});
```

As you can see, same function is repeated twice and seems inefficient especially when I have lots of functions.

So, here is my approach. I though I would turn each into a "function" and simply call them when needed:

```
jQuery(window).ready(function() {

   //Before rendered (Only if function exist)
   if ( jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.First_Function) ) {
     First_Function();
   }
   //After rendered
   jQuery.example().on('rendered', function(items) {
      First_Function();
   });

});

function First_Function()
{
jQuery('#button_A').click(function(){
      jQuery('#button_B').click();
    });
}
```

Now here is my question. Am I doing it right?

Comment: You don't especially need to wrap your callback by a function:  `element.on('event',First_Function);`

Comment: In general yes, but `jQuery.fn.First_Function` will always be `undefined` unless you explicitly assign to `jQuery.fn.First_Function`. Not sure why you want to test whether the function exist. You have written it in the source, so it will exist.

Comment: Oh i see, I guess I misunderstood its purpose. So, simple "First_Function();" is all needed ?